# Changing primary color in Bootstrap is not working?

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am creating an react app and I have installed Bootstrap React.

I wanted to change the primary color, which is blue, so I went to `bootstrap/scss/variable.scss`

Then I changed the following:

`$blue:    #445448 !default;`

Therefore, changing all the `$primary:       $blue !default;`

but still, primary color give me blue color?

I stopped my server, `npm start` again, but nothing working.

Comment: Don't use !default .. use `$blue:    #445448;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a file called `custom.scss` for example and add the following:

```
// override Bootstrap variables here
// override the primary Bootstrap color
$primary: #12a2f9;

@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"
```

Note that you should add the variables overrides before the actual bootstrap import.

And import this file before the `main.scss` or after the bootstrap import in the `App.js` or `index.js`

Edit: assuming this is your project root structure, do as follows:

```
    components/
    App.js
    main.scss
    custom.scss
    index.js
    App.test.js
```

You'll write this in the `App.js` for example:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
// This import contains the custom variables written above
import "./custom.scss";
// This import contains the actual scss code
import "./main.scss";

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer !
To be clear, (i'm a newbie) I must create a custome.scss in the node_modules\bootstrap\scss ?
Then, in it, write $primary: #12a2f9; and import it in bootstrap.sccs  with @import "custom" on the top of the import ?
And in make import of custom in my index.js, before my import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

Comment: @JéromeBORGA, It depends on the directory structure in your project, but no, that custom.scss file will be in the css folder or the root of your project because you'll import it into the App.js or the index.js files. I'll edit the answer to include what I'm describing here.

Comment: @JéromeBORGA I've updated the answer, please see if this helps you.

Comment: ok thanks a lot i'm trying this and i'll come to back you !!

Comment: ok, so first of all my boostrap is imported in this way : import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'; in index.js so before this, i wrote import './styles/custom.scss'; and still, i get blue as primary color :( what did i missed  ?
EDIT : ok so i delete the import of boottrap.min.css and it worked, but i some bootstrap elements are missing

Comment: @JéromeBORGA Remove that import and do as I specified above, first create a file called `custom.scss` with the content above, then, import it in `index.js`; If you have any scss/sass code that should override/add new styles, add it in a `main.scss` file and add it after the custom.scss import as specified above in the second code block.

Comment: EDIT : ok so i works like a charm, i just deleted  import of boottrap.min.css in my index.js but i wonder how does my bootstrap element are imported ?Thanks anyway it's working :))

Comment: @JéromeBORGA It works because you're importing the Bootstrap sass files into the `custom.scss` file above, this is the recommended way per the React documentation to customize Bootstrap files. Check it here => https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-bootstrap/